# How can I upgrade from Ubuntu Intrepid 8.10 to Jaunty 9.04 when old-releases no longer has the necessary packages?

Tags: ubuntu-9.04

I changed my sources.list to:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

I tried installing `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core` but i get this error:

```
1 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 2506kB/2555kB of archives.
After this operation, 4346kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com intrepid-updates/main update-manager-core 1:0.93.34
  404 Not Found
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com intrepid-security/main dpkg 1.14.20ubuntu6.3
  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.14.20ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.93.34_amd64.deb  404 Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Running apt-get update or --fix-missing returns the same errors.

How can I successfully upgrade from Intrepid Ibex to Jaunty 9.04?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` before your install command?

Answer (score 1):

`wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.14.20ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb`

`wget http://www.ftp.uni-erlangen.de/pub/pc/TheOpenCD/old-images/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.93.34_amd64.deb`

`dpkg -i dpkg_1.14.20ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb update-manager-core_0.93.34_amd64.deb`

Answer (score -5):

A quick scan over the contents of the repository shows that they appear to have changed the architecture from amd64 to ia64 for that release, don't ask me why.

You should be able to solve this problem by adding a file `01internal` (or any other name you like) to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.  The file should look like this:

```
APT::Architecture "ia64";
```

Then re-run `apt-get update` and hopefully it should start working.

Also, it's good practice to do a `apt-get dist-upgrade` when moving between releases.  It's possible they worked this wrinkle out so that a dist-upgrade will go smoothly without the above magic, but I don't have the appropriate machines to test that theory on.

Comment: Unfortunately adding that line gives: E: Internal Error, Could not perform immediate configuration (2) on libunwind7

Comment: ia64 is for itanium and not for amd64 - it's a different architecture

Comment: Quintessential example of "knowing just enough to be dangerous."